# Who was the original author of logrotate and what year was it written?

Tags: history, logrotate

We can't find any information about when the original version of logrotate was authored and who wrote it.Do you have idea?

Answer (score 10):

The obvious thing to do would be to go to the logrotate home page and look around for some version history.

There you can find the original 0.1 release in version control, and [the manual page for that release](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/browser/tags/0-1/logrotate.8) gives the author as "Erik Troan <ewt@redhat.com>" and the date as "Mon Nov 18 1996".

This took about a minute.